# How to get values in nested dictionary according to keys given by lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get values in a nested dictionary according to keys given by lists.

Here is my code:

```
  ops = {
    'OP1' : {'W1':5, 'w3':6, 'w4':7, 'w5':9},
    'OP3' : {'W21':61, 'w22':56, 'w23':76, 'w24':96},
    'OP4' : {'W31':61, 'w32':56, 'w33':76, 'w34':96},
    'OP5' : {'W41':61, 'w42':56, 'w43':76, 'w44':96},

}

lsta = ['OP1', 'OP3', 'OP4', 'OP5']
lstd = ['w3', 'w22', 'w32', 'w44']
```

#I tried

```
for i in lsta:
    lste=[]
    for ele in lstd:
        if ele == ops_machine[i]:
            e = ops_machine[i][ele]


KeyError: 'OP1'
```

What I want are the correponding values of each key given by lstd, which means:
    result = [6, 56, 56, 96]

Could someone help me please ?  Thanks

Comment: What is `ops`?  I see `ops_machine` in your posted code, but no `ops`.

Comment: `[ ops_machine[d1][d2] for d1, d2 in zip(lsta, lstd)]` returns the result as expected

Comment: You're mapping floats to indexes with a rather odd distribution: 0.00 to  0.166 => 0, 0.167 to 0.499 => 1, 0.500 to 0.833 => 2, 0.834 to 1.00 => 3.  Assuming a random distribution of floats indexes 0 and 3 each have 16.7 % chance of occurring and 1 and 2 have each have a 33.3% chance of occurring.  Was this intentional?

Comment: `[vs[round(ind * (len(vs)-1))] for k, ind in zip(lsta, individual[3:7]) for vs in [list(ops_machine[k].values())]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a nested loop, when you should be iterating over both lists at the same time. You can use `zip` for that:

```
[ops[d1][d2] for d1, d2 in zip(lsta, lstd)]
# [6, 56, 56, 96]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you to take your time to help me. I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I got the following error: 
  File "<ipython-input-155-2ee65ea8eb50>", line 46, in <listcomp>
    [ops[d1][d2] for d1, d2 in zip(lsta, lstd)]

KeyError: 'OP1'

Comment: That's telling you that the outer dictionary does not contain 'OP1', which is not the case in the shared example @campioni

Comment: Each dictionary has different keys, I think the problem is that, but I do not know how to fix that.

Comment: Yes, in my dic there is 'OP1'. I will edit my question and tap the whole code.

Comment: @campioni this sol is working for the example you've shared. Please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing where this raises an error

Comment: I found the error. Thank you very much. Your proposition works very well! :)

Answer (score 1):

This does the job:

```py
lsta = ['OP1', 'OP3', 'OP4', 'OP5']
lstd = ['w3', 'w31', 'w4', 'w51']


ops = {
       'OP1' : {'W1':5, 'w3':6, 'w4':7, 'w5':9},
       'OP3' : {'W11':61, 'w31':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
       'OP4' : {'W11':61, 'w4':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
       'OP5' : {'W11':61, 'w666':56, 'w41':76, 'w51':96},
    }
for i in lsta:
    if i in ops.keys():
        sub_dict = ops[i]
        for j in lstd:
            if j in sub_dict.keys():
                print (sub_dict[j])
```